# Почему не работает пример с наследованием?

Tags: java, ооп, наследование

Доброго времени суток.

Изучая механизм наследования Java, возник следующий вопрос: написал простой пример, в котором используется наследование классов, но IDE запускает его с ошибками. Пример выглядит следующим образом:

```
package testInheritancePackage;

public class Main {
    A a1 = new A();
    A b1 = new B();
    B b2 = new B();

    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println(a1.i);
        System.out.println(b1.i);
        System.out.println(b2.i);

        System.out.println(a1.mthd());
        System.out.println(b1.mthd());
        System.out.println(b2.mthd());
    }
}
```

```
package testInheritancePackage;

public class A {
    int i = 10;

    public String mthd() {
        return ("parent method");
    }
}
```

```
package testInheritancePackage;

public class B extends A {
    int i = 5;

    @Override
    public String mthd() {
        return ("child overridden method");
    }

    public String mthd_child() {
        return ("child own method");
    }
}
```

Имеются ли в данном коде ошибка или проблема связана с чем-то другим?

Благодарю.

Comment: А с какими ошибками выполняется у Вас код?

Comment: Пардон, поправил метод main(), конечно же. Ошибка следующая: `cannot make a static reference to the non-static field`. Но ведь поля в данном примере и есть нестатические?

Comment: Из статических методов обращение должно быть к статическим переменным, коими Ваши a1,b1,b2 не являются. Объявите их статиком либо объявляйте внутри main

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка в том, что статические методы класса могут получать доступ только к статическим полям и методам этого класса. У Вас же переменные `a1`, `b1`, `b2` нестатические, а метод `main`, из которого Вы к ним обращаетесь - статический. Правильно будет так:

```
static A a1 = new A();
static A b1 = new B();
static B b2 = new B();
```

Comment: Да, большое спасибо, проблема была именно в этом. Единственный момент, для объекта `static A b1 = new B();` метод `b1.mthd()` выдает строку `child overridden method`. Но ведь мы _сужаем_ область видимости методов данного объекта до класса A, верно? Разве `b1.mthd()` не должен возвращать строку `parent method`?

Comment: @Dmitry08 Нет. Вы создали объект класса `B`. А поскольку в *Java* все методы виртуальные, будет вызван метод ***реального*** класса, т.е. `B`. В этом и есть суть полиморфизма. Иными словами, мы объявляем переменную с типом ***предка***, но храним в ней ***потомка*** и поведение определяется именно тем, что там хранится.

Comment: Полностью согласен с этим. Но почему, в таком случае, `b1.i` выдает нам значение `10`, а не `5`? Почему механизм, скажем так, вывода для метода реализован в пользу дочернего класса, а для поля - в пользу родительского?

Comment: Потому что поля (переменные) не виртуальные, а переопределяемые. Поля будут выбраны из ***объявленного*** класса, а методы - из ***реального***. Если хотите получить "виртуальные" поля, используйте сеттеры и геттеры, а переменные объявляйте приватными. Кстати, это общепринятая практика. А вот почему при разработке языка пошли именно путём переопределения, мне ответить сложно. Технически возможны обе реализации.

Comment: Похоже, полностью разобрался с данным вопросом. Благодарю.

Answer (score 3):

Вы пытаетесь в статическом методе `main` обратиться к нестатическим полям класса, а это невозможно. Сделайте поля классов A B и С также статическими

Comment: Пожалуй, сделать переменные `a1`, `b1` и `b2` статическими будет более подходящим вариантом. В любом случае, большое спасибо.

Comment: Я это и хотел сказать, но жажда халявных баллов накрыла меня с головой и я опечатался